# Pattern Matching String Split $

Tags: scala

Hello currently I have the following string:

```
"STRING$INTEGER$STRING$STRING"
```

How can I pattern match that in scala?
Currently I know that I can use .split, but that produces a `Array[String]` my regex is flawed I could match everything against (.*) but that will handle the second as a String but it's an int, is there a way to have

`data match {}`

Comment: What exactly is the problem with `.split` returning an `Array[String]`? You question is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indead use a regex, but everything you match will be a `String`.

```
val format = """(\w+)\$(\d+)\$(\w+)\$(\w+)""".r

"hello$5$foo$bar" match {
  case format(s1, i, s2, s3) => // i is a String
    val n = i.toInt
}
```

You could also create an extractor which could use the regex above or `split`.

```
object Format {
  def unapply(string: String) = string.split("""\$""") match {
    case Array(s1, i, s2, s3) => 
      Try(i.toInt).toOption.map(i => (s1, i, s2, s3))
  }
}

"hello$5$foo$bar" match {
  case Format(s1, i, s2, s3) => i + 5  // i is an Int
}
// Int = 10
```

Comment: Hey thanks, thats basically what I did. But I found out myself. Still thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is plenty unclear, but I guess you might need something like this?

```
val string = "STRING$INTEGER$STRING$STRING"
val regex = """(\w+)\$(\w+)\$(\w+)\$(\w+)""".r

string match {
  case regex(s1, i, s2, s3) =>
    s"$s1, $i, $s2, $s3"
  case _ =>
    "error"
}

|> res0: String = STRING, INTEGER, STRING, STRING
```

Answer (score 0):

To separate a string `val s = "abc$123$foo$bar"` by `$` consider

```
val xs = s.split("\\$")
xs: Array[String] = Array(abc, 123, foo, bar)
```

To collect all the integer values in the resulting array consider for instance

```
xs.flatMap( s => scala.util.Try(s.toInt).toOption )
res: Array[Int] = Array(123)
```

were we try to convert each string into an integer value; in case of failure it delivers a `None` which is flattened out.